# How to send multiple Json data i the single json request in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I am looking to send(POST) multiple data  in the same Json request to my service , here is the example:

```
{
  "contributionRequest":{
  "contributionData":[ 
                      {"startDate":"2010-01- 01”dataItemName":"XYZ",
                       "dataItemValue":"",
                       "expireDate":"",
                       "inputScale":"",
                       "endDate":"",
                       "identifier":"MSFT",
                       "publishDate":"",
                       "trait":"",
                       "fiscalPeriod":"FY1",
                       "currency":""},

                      {"startDate":"2014-01-01”dataItemName":"ERT",
                       "dataItemValue":"",
                       "expireDate":"",
                       "inputScale":"",
                       "endDate":"",
                       "identifier":"MSFT",
                       "publishDate":"",
                       "trait":"",
                       "fiscalPeriod":"FY1",
                       "currency":"USD"}
                    ],
                    "acceptPartialRequest":true,
                    "sharingLevel":"self",
                    "uuid":"PAXTRA77385",
                    "clientDateTime":"2014-04-24T16:05:05.480Z"}
}
```

I have tried thread group users/loop controllers but they create different requests, problem is I want to load thousands of records in the same request. here in the contributor request I wan to load thousands of record but they should all go in the same request

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to send all the data to this request once 
or
Use same/single request to send multiple requests changing parameter values every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using one of the following solutions:

**Solution 1**

Use separate [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to populate your large request entity, store it to JMeter property and pass it to "main" thread group. A variety of approaches can be used here:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString)
- [__stringFromFile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)

Once you have huge JSON you can [use it in different thread groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) via converting it to JMeter Property.

**Solution 2**

Add a [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to your request containing code to construct your JSON data, something like

```
//code to generate JSON data
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("contributionRequest", contributionData);
....
String data = object.toJSONString();
vars.put("request", data);
```

And then refer to it as `{request}` in your HTTP Request.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for details on JMeter extension via Beanshell scripting